# Black screen when connecting via RDP to a Win 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, login, rdp, 64-bit

Recently (eg. in the last week or two), when I RDP to one of our servers running Windows Serve 2003 64bit, the login screen is black.

If you can guess what it is prompting, then you can still login, and once you get past the login screen the desktop displays correctly.

Any suggestions as to what would have caused the login part to be blank?

-dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[From KB 906510](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=906510):

> This issue occurs if all the values
>   under the following registry subkey
>   are set to "0 0 0":
>   HKEY_USERS.Default\Control
>   Panel\Colors
>
> **Note:** The value data "0 0
>   0" means black.
>
> **Export the registry subkey from
>   another Windows Server 2003-based
>   computer**
>
> 1. Click Start, point to Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then
>      click OK.
> 2. Locate the following registry subkey:
>        HKEY_USERS.Default\Control Panel\Colors
> 3. Right-click the Colors registry subkey, and then click Export.
> 4. In the File name box, type a name for the file.
> 5. Note the location where you will save the file, and then click Save.
>
> **Import the registry subkey into the
>   affected computer**
>
> 1. Click Start, point to Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then
>      click OK.
> 2. On the File menu, click Import.
> 3. Double-click the .reg file that you want to import.
> 4. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't be able to tell if this is client or server related, but as a start:

[Server]

I would check the RDP settings against another server, as well as the resultant set of policy against another server as it applies for "Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services"

[Client]

Make sure you have RDC 6.1, and then try turning various graphical optimisations off/on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out in Safe Mode .. same?

I think the color scheme might be messed up, so go in via Safe Mode or however you can, and change that :)

You can update in the registry as well ...

HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Colors

Answer (score -1):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Colors]
"ActiveBorder"="212 208 200"
"ActiveTitle"="10 36 106"
"AppWorkSpace"="128 128 128"
"Background"="102 111 116"
"ButtonAlternateFace"="181 181 181"
"ButtonDkShadow"="64 64 64"
"ButtonFace"="212 208 200"
"ButtonHilight"="255 255 255"
"ButtonLight"="212 208 200"
"ButtonShadow"="128 128 128"
"ButtonText"="0 0 0"
"GradientActiveTitle"="166 202 240"
"GradientInactiveTitle"="192 192 192"
"GrayText"="128 128 128"
"Hilight"="10 36 106"
"HilightText"="255 255 255"
"HotTrackingColor"="0 0 128"
"InactiveBorder"="212 208 200"
"InactiveTitle"="128 128 128"
"InactiveTitleText"="212 208 200"
"InfoText"="0 0 0"
"InfoWindow"="255 255 225"
"Menu"="212 208 200"
"MenuText"="0 0 0"
"Scrollbar"="212 208 200"
"TitleText"="255 255 255"
"Window"="255 255 255"
"WindowFrame"="0 0 0"
"WindowText"="0 0 0"

Comment: What is this mess meant to mean? You can't just dump random registry strings without an explanation.